# Azure Redis, How to scale in .NET, using the Microsoft Azure Management Libraries (MAML)

Tags: azure, redis, azure-sdk-.net, azure-redis-cache

Can anyone give example of using the Microsoft Azure Management Libraries (MAML) to scale the Redis Cache Service ?

I must use older version  Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis.dll, v0.9.0.0, and so the RedisManagementClient do not receive token, but only credentials. In this case an exception appears

> "AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed. The 'Authorization'
>   header is missing."

Here is the code I'm using:

```
  public static void ScaleRedis(eSubscriptionType subscriptionType)
    {

            RedisManagementClient client = new RedisManagementClient(AzureCredentials.GetCredentials(subscriptionType));


            var redisParams = new RedisCreateOrUpdateParameters()
            {
                Properties = new RedisProperties(version, new Sku(redisSKUName, redisSKUFamily, redisSKUCapacity), false),
                Location = redisCacheRegion
            };
            client.Redis.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, cacheName, redisParams);


    }
```

Comment: I have updated my reply. Any concerns, please let me know.

Comment: It's seems like the right answer, only the relation to AD was new to us and now we try to get the clientId and tenentId, when we'll manage I'll mark it as best answer. I see in the code a link to Redis access -keys, but where is the use of the access-key ?

Comment: [access-keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-configure#access-keys) combined with endpoint is used as connection string when you connect your Azure Redis Cache with client library (e.g. StackExchange.Redis), you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache).

Comment: Since you are using MAML to manage (create/update) your Azure Redis Cache, there is no relation with `access-keys`. You just need to follow the resources within my Note to create your ad app and retrieve the token. Any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I must use older version **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis.dll**, v0.9.0.0, and so the RedisManagementClient do not receive token, but only credentials.

As I known, the library named `Microsoft.Azure.*` is used to call [ARM REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/index?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with [TokenCloudCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.tokencloudcredentials.aspx), while `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.*` could work with [CertificateCloudCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.certificatecloudcredentials.aspx).

If you manage Redis Cache by using MAML with `CertificateCloudCredentials`, you would get the following error message:

`AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing.`

Leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), you could find the detailed error as follows:

[image]

Considering you are using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis.dll (v0.9.0)`, the code used to manage Redis Cache would look like this:

```html
TokenCloudCredentials tokenCredential = new TokenCloudCredentials("{your-subscriptionId}", "{token}");
RedisManagementClient client = new RedisManagementClient(tokenCredential);
var redisParams = new RedisCreateOrUpdateParameters()
{
    Properties = new RedisProperties(version, new Sku(redisSKUName, redisSKUFamily, redisSKUCapacity)),
    Location = redisCacheRegion
};
client.Redis.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, cacheName, redisParams);
```

**Note:**

- For generating the token, you could reuse the `GetAuthorizationHeader` function from [here](https://github.com/rustd/RedisSamples/blob/master/ManageCacheUsingMAML/Program.cs).
- For setup your app for Authenticating Azure Resource Manager with Active Directory

  You need to [set up an AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application) and [assign role (Contributor) to your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role) to manage your Redis Cache via MAML. For more details, you could refer to this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/index?redirectedfrom=MSDN#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad).

**UPDATE**

Here is my `packages.config`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis" version="0.9.0-preview" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> To scale your Azure Redis Cache instances using the [Microsoft Azure
>   Management Libraries (MAML)](http://azure.microsoft.com/updates/management-libraries-for-net-release-announcement/), call the
>   **IRedisOperations.CreateOrUpdate** method and pass in the new size for
>   the **RedisProperties.SKU.Capacity**.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // For instructions on getting the access token, see
    // https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/cache-configure/#access-keys
    string token = GetAuthorizationHeader();

    TokenCloudCredentials creds = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId,token);

    RedisManagementClient client = new RedisManagementClient(creds);
    var redisProperties = new RedisProperties();

    // To scale, set a new size for the redisSKUCapacity parameter.
    redisProperties.Sku = new Sku(redisSKUName,redisSKUFamily,redisSKUCapacity);
    redisProperties.RedisVersion = redisVersion;
    var redisParams = new RedisCreateOrUpdateParameters(redisProperties, redisCacheRegion);
    client.Redis.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName,cacheName, redisParams);
}
```

> For more information, see the [Manage Redis Cache using MAML
>   sample](https://github.com/rustd/RedisSamples/tree/master/ManageCacheUsingMAML).

Source: [How to Scale Azure Redis Cache # Scale using MAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-scale#scale-using-maml)

Comment: I add more information to the question, so to be more specific with the version I'm using.

Comment: Is your Redis cache created using Azure Resource Manager or Azure Service Management? Your nuget version is release in 2014 and is too old to support the token authentication.